# Declaring never changing variable inside or outside component

Tags: reactjs

I've 2 examples. Main difference is declaring some variable inside and outside component. Component itself changes state. So declaring never changing (neither state or prop dependent) variable outside component can save some memory, re-creating, or something? Or either option completely fine?

**Option A**

```
import React from 'react';

const menu = [
  { slug: '/a', label: 'Label A' },
  { slug: '/b', label: 'Label B' },
  { slug: '/c', label: 'Label C' },
];

const Example = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
        toggle show
      </button>
      {show && (
        <div className="menu">
          {menu.map((m) => (
            <a key={m.slug} href={m.slug}>
              {m.label}
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

**Option B**

```
import React from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const menu = [
    { slug: '/a', label: 'Label A' },
    { slug: '/b', label: 'Label B' },
    { slug: '/c', label: 'Label C' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
        toggle show
      </button>
      {show && (
        <div className="menu">
          {menu.map((m) => (
            <a key={m.slug} href={m.slug}>
              {m.label}
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 1):

A is indeed slightly better - in B, the `menu` array of objects is created every single time the `Example` re-renders.

That said, unless the object structure is unreasonably huge, and the component re-renders quite frequently, it's quite unlikely to have any noticeable impact at all.

Comment: > array of objects is created every single time.

When they created every time, older one clears memory? If yes, can I say memory-wise even it's huge component it's still same?

Answer (score 1):

Although [the Babel transpiled version](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAogDwIYFsAOAbApjAvDACgEo8A-GAbwCgYZRJYUswBXPGAbRtspggxYBzAFwwA5AHokYgDQwMSAEZYMosQBklKmAEExMAL4zutCnwEjxExbPlbV4zcowwAQvqMne_IWonBbBWc1J20AYQ9jWgBdAG5uACcsKBYEsEIvAB4AEwBLADdSCgApAGUAeQA5ADpoXLBBXIAzAE8CJlYiA0yJPMLuIniDeKoqemgYDpZyllh8Lh5vCz9pOSCVEPtdSK8zH0tJGzX7Tec3HcW95asA4-DHLYjDKJg4sfAJxFRMLBm5whIuHIBCyfSKZSqtSg9UarXazGmsy6PTBAxGVCAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.15.8&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) of the code may present an optimization and performance boost, in the object recreation phase (which is really FAST by itself); you must consider the final output which is sent to a browser and processed by a browser engine.

Nowadays utilizing a minification at end of your build process is an essential thing. Besides their transpiled version difference, there are certain circumstances where webpack embeds outside variables (e.g. `menu`) directly by stated variables in the minification process making those completely the same.

I believe when you contemplate these sorts of adjustments, you must not do them for performance benchmark. There are other reasons I think one might do these things, e .g. using a variable instead of typing `rtl` directly inside your JSX, or doing outer component variable referencing because of your project code structure

```
const t = {
  Hello: 'سلام',
  // Other translations related to this feature component...
}
// the better option is absolutely i18n
const Hello = () => <span>{t.Hello}</span>
```